# Please Recommend a good textbook on Invariance Principle.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, reference-request, contest-math

please recommend a very nice and sophisticated textbook that covers Sums and Products, Invariance and Recursive Relations.

I need one suitable for someone preparing for the IMO. thanks.

Comment: The site AoP has nice set of books you want.

Comment: I have the same question but somehow I do not seem to get any attention for my question. AOPS has books but they do not specify which ones have good problems (and lots of them) for Invariance principle. Arthur Engel's "Problem Solving Strategies" is the only book I have known which has about 60 dedicated problems to be solved using invariance. However, it would be fantastic to have more problems (probably even a dedicated book) on Invariance principle. I wish someone on this forum could recommend some source which has a really long list of good problems on Invariance principle.